# How to read my azure functions function key in python

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I am having an azure function in python. I also have my key values defined in function keys.

How to read this in python program. I see i can add key value pair in Configuration of the function app.But i need these values specific to a function.

My azure function is based on python 3.7
[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=python#obtaining-keys), You can obtain function keys programmatically by using [Key management APIs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Key-management-API#function-keys-collection-resource-adminfunctionsfunctionnamekeys)

> **Key management API**
>
> The Functions Runtime exposes a management API that
> enables consumers to programmatically add, delete, and update function
> keys.
>
> Since this API is exposed by the runtime, the **base URL is**:
> `https://<functionappname>.azurewebsites.net/`

> Function keys collection resource: **admin/functions/{functionname}/keys**
>
> GET Retrieves the function keys
>
> Request:
>
> `GET /admin/functions/{functionname}/keys`

Response

```
{
  "keys": [
    {
      "name": "keyname",
      "value": "keyvalue",
      "links": [
        {
          "rel": "self",
          "href": "https://baseuri/admin/functions/{functionname}/keys/{keyname}"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "links": [
    {
      "rel": "self",
      "href": "http://baseuri/admin/functions/{functionname}/keys"
    }
  ]
}
```